# Can Blender easily render a single image from 3D source files?

Tags: rendering, texturing

Very simple project:  I have a number of PNG image files, including textures, height map, normal map, and some masks.  I want to turn these into a single still image.

Before I invest time learning how to do this in Blender, I'd like to know whether Blender can even do this, and how easy it's likely to be.  I know a lot of the concepts of 3D rendering, but I've never used this kind of software before.

Is Blender likely to be a good choice for me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's quite hard to know what do you mean by "turn image files into a single image". If it's about rendering model with textures then obviously yes, that's what Blender does with its numerous render engines. Some information could be required if you need more details about the process, e.g do you have actually a mesh, is it unwrapped etc. You can [edit] your question

Answer (score 1):

The types of images you mention are what you would use in blender to control the surface appearance of a 3D object, that you then position and render into a 2D image.

If you want to merge multiple images into one image, you would be better off using a 2D image editing program like [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org) or [Krita](https://krita.org/en/). Another option could be using [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org) to combine them using the CLI.